# I have a SOAP Envelope inside an AJAX Call, the Request Body Displays results, but page does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, soap

I have the following code as seen below. I am using a SOAP envelope here to pull back some results in AJAX. If I look in the developer tools for IE, and go to the response body I see the results. I cannot however, seem to get them to display on the page.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope     xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                <soapenv:Body> \
                     <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                        <listName>Topics</listName> \
                        <viewFields> \
                            <ViewFields> \
                               <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                           </ViewFields> \
                        </viewFields> \
                    </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
            </soapenv:Envelope>";
        $.ajax({
            url: "mysite/subsite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            async:true,
       success: function (dataBack) {
            $("#Result").text(dataBack["d"]);
        },  error : alert("error"),
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    });

<div id="Results"></div>
```

Please advise.

Comment: is that a typo here or in your production code ...$("#Result") vs id="Result**s**"

Comment: Why would you do this? It seems like a misunderstanding and use of technologies. The better question should be what are you trying to actually do?

Comment: If you are getting the response body in console, it is likely that there is a problem with the `$("#Result").text(dataBack["d"]);` part. Perhaps `console.log(dataBack)` or `console.dir(dataBack)`, and also `console.dir($('#Result')` to verify that the response body is present and the specified element you are placing the response in can be affected as written.

Comment: When debugging Ajax, generally you want to verify that you got a 200 response header first. Any response that contains body from the server, including errors, will trip the success function, so it should not be assumed that that function automatically means success. You also want to verify the response code before proceeding.

Comment: What do you expect `dataBack["d"]` to do? It doesn't sound right.

Comment: Ok, I have looked at the issue again. Sorry, I was super sick when I posted this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx Explains what I trying to do. I added references for javascript, and sp.js. I read somewhere I needed to include MicrosoftAjax, but I don't see it listed anywhere as being hosted? Just now feeling recuperated.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is returning xml (dataBack), so `dataBack["d"]` doesn't make sense. It seems that you are confusing it with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SP2013?
You can easily call
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Topics')/Items

Refer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx

Comment: Ok, I have looked at the issue again. Sorry, I was super sick when I posted this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx Explains what I trying to do. I added references for javascript, and sp.js. I read somewhere I needed to include MicrosoftAjax, but I don't see it listed anywhere as being hosted? Just now feeling recuperated.

Comment: No, we have 2010. That was a big issue I just discovered.

Answer (score -1):

The actual answer to this question for me was... Yes, I can use the CAML Query without SOAP envelope. Instead I am using CSOM. I was missing references when I tried initially, so I started using SOAP. I found the location of the missing reference eventually, and that it was not hosted but in the Layout folder!